# Facebook Comments plugin display after reloading the page React

Tags: reactjs, facebook-comments

I'm using Facebook Comments plugin for my React website. Plugin section is displayed ONLY after reloading the page. Does anybody know the solution?

```
index.html
---
<body>
    
    <div id="root"></div>
    <div id="fb-root"></div>

    <script async defer
            crossorigin="anonymous" 
            src="https://connect.facebook.net/uk_UA/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v8.0"
            nonce="2CmNBc9x"
    ></script>

  </body>
```

```
OnlineReception.jsx // here I want to render FC plugin
---
import React from 'react';
import './css/OnlineReception.css';

const OnlineReception = (props) => {
    ...

    return (
        <div className="OnlineReception">
            ...
                <div className="fb-comments"
                  data-href="mywebsite-link-here"
                  data-numposts="10"
                  data-width=""
                ></div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default OnlineReception;
```

SDK integration is taken from [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/comments).
Also, I'm using HashRouter

```
{/* online-reception route */}
              <Route path="/online-reception" render={
                () =>
                  <OnlineReception
                    props here
                  />
              } />
```